# Is 忝い（かたじけない） used in contemporary language?

Tags: usage, expressions, archaic-language

I'm currently watching Rurouni Kenshin, and Kenshin says  忝い（かたじけない） a lot to express his gratitude. I looked it up a little and based on [this](http://www.tofugu.com/2008/02/09/how-to-talk-like-a-samurai/) it seems like it's old Samurai language, but I wonder if people use it today with no intention to be Samurai-ish? Sort of like "I appreciate it"?

Comment: I've seen people use it for comic effect sometimes, but never in any public setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. かたじけない is one of the most famous 武士語/サムライ言葉, but it's never used in ordinary conversations today.