# What's the meaning of 「かたじけない しのぶ！！」

Tags: meaning, phrases

From a manga:

> bubble1:侍達を一人残らず抹殺せよ！！！
>
> bubble2:ぐわア！！！
>
> bubble3:かたじけない しのぶ！！武器は助かった！！
>
> bubble4:いえ

I understandd the individual meanings of かたじけない and しのぶ, but with them mixed together, I can't figure it out. It was confusing then I thought maybe かたじけない was an adjective. I think something had been omitted and made the sentence a bit more friendly

also is かたじけない an adjective? Google said it's a phrase but the way written here I thought it's an い-adjective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

かたじけない is an older word that roughly means "mentally indebting".

- [Is 忝い（かたじけない） used in contemporary language?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20958/7810)

It is an i-adjective, but you can take it as a samural/ninja way to say "thank you" (= it indebts me). しのぶ seems to be a female name.

> かたじけない　しのぶ！！ *Thank you, Shinobu!!*

In manga, normal punctuation is rarely used so that you have to pay attention where spaces and line breaks are.

Comment: しのぶwas wrote without any kanji or katakana so i thought it's a word T^T so 

かたじけない is a samurai way to say thank you !?

Comment: @PinkCat Most time you can think of it "thank you" but always good to store the original meaning somewhere in the memory for such a usage as かたじけないお言葉.

Comment: @PinkCat, it's similar to ありがたい -- it's describing whatever Shinobu did for the speaker.  It's basically saying that whatever Shinobu gave to the speaker was "welcome".  This is a slightly different nuance from the English expression "thank you" (in case that has any bearing on your understanding of the story).  :)